# make two-sided plane

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, plane

I'm new to Unity, so maybe my question is too simple, but I can't solve it. I'm making something like virtual apartment designer and I use planes to draw walls, so I have its start X, end X, start Y, end Y and height. To see both sides of each wall, I decided double wall and rotate it to 180 (maybe it was wrong). But in every attempt there were failures. When I use simple `plane.Rotate` it rotates, but changes its position, (like the center is somewhere on the downside of plane). And when I use `plane.RotateArount`, position is right, but rotation isn't. 
**There is the code how I create plane**

```
public static GameObject CreatePlane(float x1, float z1, float y1, float x2, float z2, float y2, Material material, bool rotate)
{
    var go = new GameObject("plane");
    var mf = go.AddComponent(typeof(MeshFilter)) as MeshFilter;
    var mr = go.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer)) as MeshRenderer;
    var m = new Mesh();

    m.vertices = new[]
    {
        new Vector3(x1, y1, z1), 
        new Vector3(x1, y2, z1), 
        new Vector3(x2, y2, z2), 
        new Vector3(x2, y1, z2)

    };
    m.uv = new[]
    {
        new Vector2(1,1), 
        new Vector2(1,1), 
        new Vector2(1,1), 
        new Vector2(1,1), 
    };
    m.triangles = new[] {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};
   if (mr != null) mr.material = material;
    if (mf != null) mf.mesh = m;
    m.RecalculateBounds();
    m.RecalculateNormals();
    go.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
    return go;
}
```

**and my attempts of rotating:**

```
plane.AddComponent<RectTransform>().transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,180);
plane.transform.RotateAround(new Vector3(0,1,0),plane.transform.position,  180);
plane.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,180);
plane.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,180);
```

Thank you in advance

Also, I've noticed, that when I'm rotating this plane in Editor, coordinates of position are changing too. Is it normal..?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a Cube and give it a scale in each axis. It would be much simpler and you could rotate them only in the Y-axis and you are done. At the end just position all the cubes where you want them and you are technically done. Is there any other reason you want planes instead of cubes ?

Comment: I need to have possibility change color of each side. As I know, it's impossible  with cube

Comment: It is possible if you create a Cube inside Blender and assign 6 Materials to the cube, one for each face. You can change them as you like inside Unity. You will also need to UV unwrap these faces.